# Direct instantiation of `typing.Union` in Python

Tags: python, typing, pydantic

I would like to instantiate a [typing `Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) of two classes derived from [`pydantic.BaseModel`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) directly. However I get a `TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing.Union`.

All examples I have seen declare `Union` as an attribute of a class (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58301364/pydantic-and-subclasses-of-abstract-class)).

Below is the minimum example I would like to use.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union

class A(BaseModel):
    a: int

class B(A):
    b: int

class C(A):
    c: str

MyUnion = Union[B, C, A]
mu = MyUnion(a=666, c='foo')  #  This command throws the TypeError
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is the error I obtain

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-8163e3490185> in <module>
----> 1 MyUnion()

c:\program files\python37\lib\typing.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    668             raise TypeError(f"Type {self._name} cannot be instantiated; "
    669                             f"use {self._name.lower()}() instead")
--> 670         result = self.__origin__(*args, **kwargs)
    671         try:
    672             result.__orig_class__ = self

c:\program files\python37\lib\typing.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    327
    328     def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
--> 329         raise TypeError(f"Cannot instantiate {self!r}")
    330
    331     def __instancecheck__(self, obj):

TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing.Union
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate a Union, that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: A union represents „one of A, B or C“. It seems you want „all of A, B and C“, which is not a union.

Comment: As per the above comments, a `Union` is a type hint, telling python what type a variable should be. It is not a class in its own right. Itdoes not represent the amalgamation of two types or classes into a new combined type/class.

Answer (score 9):

That's not how Union works.

Union is the same thing as the `union` in C.

It means that the variable can be either of type A or of type B.

For example

```
def f(a: Union[int, str]) -> None:
   ...
```

This means that `a` can be an `int` or a `str`, a subclass of those and nothing else.

Comment: No, it is not the same thing as a union in C at all.

Comment: Yes it is. But please if you say that I'm wrong you should also say what is wrong…

Comment: A union in C is a specific thing, a piece of memory that can be interpreted as *either one type or another* at *any given moment*. I.E. `union foo {int x; float y};` then something like `union foo; foo.x = 4;`, then I can do something like `printf( "%d\n", foo.x); printf("%d\n", foo.y)`, that is, the union acts like a struct with members, just that these members share memory. Python has nothing like this. While, from a type theory perspective, this could be considered a sum type, which is what Union means in Python, that doesn't mean Python Unions are like C unions.

Comment: Well in python everything is a pointer, so pointer to union…

Comment: python *doesn't have pointers*. This really has nothing to do with C unions

Comment: A C Union is both *at the same time*. A Python union is a type annotation that indicates a variable is either or, but not both at the same time

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers arithmetic, it does have pointers. It even has a function to compare pointer values…

Comment: No, Python does not have pointers (unless you are talking about`ctypes`)

Comment: `a = {}; b = a; b['aaa'] = 'aaa'; del a['aaa']` why doesn't that fail?

Comment: because, there is only one object with two different names in that namespace.

Comment: The name for this is: "pointer"

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is `parse_obj_as`:

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#parsing-data-into-a-specified-type

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as
from typing import Union

class A(BaseModel):
    a: int

class B(A):
    b: int

class C(A):
    c: str

MyUnion = Union[B, C, A]
mu = parse_obj_as(MyUnion, {"a":666, "c":'foo'}) 
mu
# >>> C(a=666, c='foo')
```

Comment: The mostly useful answer.
The only one remark - now this function is depricated and you use [TypeAdapter](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/type_adapter/) instead:
TypeAdapter(MyUnion).validate_python({"a":666, "c":'foo'})

Answer (score 3):

I know that I don't have exactly the same issue as the question, but for others that land here, I resolved my issue by changing `Union(int, blah)` to `Union[int, blah]`

The important thing being that I accidentally used parenthesis instead of square brackets. :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is a factory function, one that guesses which of `A`, `B`, or `C` to instantiate based on the keyword arguments presented in the call.

For example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union

class A(BaseModel):
    a: int

class B(A):
    b: int

class C(A):
    c: str

def a_b_or_c(**kwargs) -> Union[B, C, A]:
    if 'c' in kwargs:
        return C(**kwargs)
    elif 'b' in kwargs:
        return B(**kwargs)
    elif 'a' in kwargs:
        return A(**kwargs)
    else:
        raise Exception("I don't know what class you want")

my = a_b_or_c(a=666, c='foo')
```

`a_b_or_c`, of course, could do more extensive testing of the arguments found in `kwargs`, for example to prevent passing arguments that none of `A`, `B`, or `C` are expecting.

Comment: All of that can be achieved with this `typedload` module I wrote. It'd be something like `load(kwargs, Union[A, B, C])`, but the classes need to use typing or attrs as well to be recognised.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this behavior?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union, List

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class I(ValidatedDC):
    i: int


@dataclass
class F(ValidatedDC):
    f: float


@dataclass
class S(ValidatedDC):
    s: str


@dataclass
class MyUnion(ValidatedDC):
    data: List[Union[I, F, S]]


my_union = MyUnion([{'i': 1}, {'s': 'S'}, {'f': 0.2}])
assert my_union.get_errors() is None
assert my_union == MyUnion(data=[I(i=1), S(s='S'), F(f=0.2)])
```

ValidatedDC: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc